# error grave con checkbox de materialize.css

Tags: php, pdo

Hola amigos resulta que estoy teniendo problemas con los checkbox de `materialize.css`.

Estoy haciendo una consulta por orden alfabético pero cuando trato de hacer la selección de cualquier medicamento solo me deja seleccionar el primero de cada letra, pero si le quito el `css`, me funciona perfectamente y puedo seleccionar el que sea.

¿Alguien sabe como quitar los css a un checkbox o algo por el estilo?

Anexo el código el imágenes para que vean.

```
    <?php
//CONSULTA LETRA A
$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM medicamentos WHERE nombre_medicamento LIKE 'A%%' ORDER BY id;");
if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){

echo "<form class='col s12' action='recipe_medico.php' 
name='frmContacto' method='post'>";

echo "<div class='letra' align='justify' 
style='margin-left: -18px; overflow: auto; width: 260px; height: 480px;'>
<div 'center-align black-text thin' style='font-size: 22px;'>A<hr></div>
<div class='letra' align='justify' style='width: 370px;'>";

while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

echo ("<div class='letra' align='justify' style='width: 370px;'>
<p><input type='checkbox' name='chk_group[]' id='chk1' value='{$linea['id']}' > 
<label class='black-text' for='chk1'>{$linea['nombre_medicamento']}&nbsp;&nbsp;
{$linea['presentacion_medicamento']}</label></p></div>
</div>");
}
}
```

//FIN CONSULTA LETRA A

[image: con css]

[image: sin css]

ahora en mysql para guardar lo implementaba así:

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['guardar'])){
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$fecha=$_REQUEST['fecha'];
$cedula=$_REQUEST['cedula'];
$idmedicamentos=$_REQUEST['chk_group'];

  include("conexion.php");
  $sql="SELECT * FROM receta_medica WHERE id='$id' AND fecha='$fecha' AND idmedicamentos='$idmedicamentos[$i]'";
  $res=mysql_query($sql,$link);
  $nrows=mysql_num_rows($res);
  if($nrows==0){
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($idmedicamentos); $i++) {
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO receta_medica (id,fecha,cedula,idmedicamentos) 
  VALUES ('$id','$fecha','$cedula','$idmedicamentos[$i]')", $link);
        }

echo "<script>alert ('Registro Guardado');</script>
<META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:recipe_medico.php>";
          }
  else echo "<div class='registro'><script>alert ('Disculpe, El Paciente ya tiene realizado un recipe para esta Fecha debe Esperar la proxima consulta');</script> 
  <META HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' CONTENT=0;URL=http:recipe_medico.php></div>";
}
?>
```

como ahora utilizo PDO como podrida aplicar lo del for o ese mismo for me sirve

```
<!-- proceso para registrar-->

<?php
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
  $sql = "SELECT id FROM receta_medica WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
  $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
  $check->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
  $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
  $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
  if ($contador > 0) {
  $check->closeCursor();

$mensaje = "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado ! 
</h5>
</div>";
header("refresh:5;examenes_laboratorio.php");
$sql = false;
    }else{



$sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO receta_medica (id,fk_cedula,fk_examen_laboratorio,fecha) 
  VALUES (:id, :fk_cedula, :fk_examen_laboratorio[], :fecha)");
$sql->bindParam(':id',$_POST['id']);
$sql->bindParam(':fk_cedula',$_POST['fk_cedula']);
$sql->bindParam(':fk_examen_laboratorio',$_POST['chk_group']);
$sql->bindParam(':fecha',$_POST['fecha']);
$sql->execute();
    }


if($sql)
{

$mensaje ="<div class='col s12 card-panel teal lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !
</h5>
</div>";
header("refresh:5;examenes_laboratorio.php");

}
}
?>
<!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```

Comment: Formatea bien tu pregunta

Comment: En el segundo echo tienes un div con llamada a clases de css que no están asignadas.

Comment: hay mismo esta declarado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En materialize los checkboxes son invisibles. La cajita que ves se genera usando la seudopropiedad `:after` y en realidad el acto de checkear o descheckear se hace mediante el `label`.

El label sabe qué checkbox está modificando porque tiene el atributo `for` apuntando al ID del checkbox. Y aquí viene el problema: todos tus checkbox tienen el mismo ID, porlo que los tres labels tratan de modificar el mismo elemento.

Cuando le asignas el mismo ID a varios elementos no es que el browser propague a todos ellos lo que haces en referencia a ese ID. Más bien se queda con alguno de los que tienen ese ID e ignora el resto.

Puedes usar el campo campo `id` de la consulta, y tu sentencia `echo` quedaría:

```
echo ("<div class='letra' align='justify' style='width: 370px;'>
<p><input type='checkbox' name='chk_group[]' id='chk1{$linea['id']}' value='{$linea['id']}' > 
<label class='black-text' for='chk1{$linea['id']}'>{$linea['nombre_medicamento']}&nbsp;&nbsp;
{$linea['presentacion_medicamento']}</label></p></div>
</div>");
```

O un poco más legible:

```
echo "<div class='letra' align='justify' style='width: 370px;'>";
  echo "<p>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='chk_group[]' id='chk1{$linea['id']}' value='{$linea['id']}' />";
    echo "<label class='black-text' for='chk1{$linea['id']}'>$linea['nombre_medicamento']}&nbsp;&nbsp;    {$linea['presentacion_medicamento']}</label>";
  echo "</p>";
echo "</div>";
```

Con lo cual de paso queda en evidencia que te sobra una etiqueta de cierre de div.

Comment: amenadiel me gusto mucho tu comentario y me ha servido me has salvado la vida, gracias amigo no sabes cuanto sufrí por eso...

Comment: amenadiel, ahora una ultima cosa en mysql para guardar lo implementaba asi

Comment: @yoclens en la versión mysql_query, estás insertando N registros con el mismo ID. ¿Cómo puede ser eso? en tu tabla de recetas tienes N registros para una receta donde N es la cantidad de medicamentos prescritos?

Comment: te explico en mi tabla receta_medica guardo el id que es auto incremen, la fecha de creacion del recipe medico, el idmedicamentos el el id de los medicamentos y por ultimo la cedula del paciente que se le genera ese recipe medico en ese modelo me funciona perfectamente ahora lo que me refiero es que si ese for lo puedo utilizar en pdo porque me da error

id ---- fecha ---- idmedicamentos ---- cedula
1       02/03/2017      25               87654321       
2       02/03/2017      10               87654321        
3       02/03/2017      8                14622737

Comment: ya lo pude resolver anexo como deberia quedar     ` for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['fk_examen_laboratorio']); $i++) {
  $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO examenes_laboratorio_pacientes (fk_cedula,fk_examen_laboratorio,fecha) VALUES 
   (:fk_cedula, :fk_examen_laboratorio, :fecha)");
  $sql->bindParam(':fk_cedula',$_POST['fk_cedula']);
  $sql->bindParam(':fk_examen_laboratorio',$_POST['fk_examen_laboratorio'][$i]);
  $sql->bindParam(':fecha',$_POST['fecha']);
  $sql->execute();`