# Error al concatenar javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://gyazo.com/ff20c1b1468edcf147d76c22cb6da0d2)

Sí lo pruebo así me funciona solo el primero
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://%3Cinput%20type=%22checkbox%22%20id='medical'%20name='medical[]'%20onClick='marcarMEDICAL()'/%3E)

la falla me aparece aquí en `<input name='M_` `+ idDiv +` `' id='M_` `+ idDiv +` `' type='checkbox' onClick='marcarMEDICAL()'/>`  cuando le doy <kbd>click</kbd> al `checkbox` no lo selecciona si le quito `+ idDiv +` funciona bien  (`+ idDiv +  =`  a un contador).
lo intente con un `name="medica[]"` para agregar varios `checkbox` en un arreglo por alguna razón no funciona  al darle <kbd>click</kbd>

ya lo intente cambiando  a `<input name='M_${idDiv}' id='M_${idDiv}' type='checkbox' onClick='marcarMEDICAL()' />`

```
    $('#masplantillas').append(`<div class='col s12'  id='divplantillas` + idDiv + `' >
                                <div class='input-field col s2 m3'>
                                    <select name='C_`+ idDiv + `' id='C_` + idDiv + `' class='browser-default validate' onChange='total(this.id)' required>
                                        <option value='' selected disabled>0</option>
                                        <option value='1'>1</option>
                                        <option value='2'>2</option>
                                        <option value='3'>3</option>
                                        <option value='4'>4</option>
                                        <option value='5'>5</option>
                                        <option value='6'>6</option>
                                        <option value='7'>7</option>
                                        <option value='8'>8</option>
                                        <option value='9'>9</option>
                                        <option value='10'>10</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class='input-field col s7 m4'>
                                    <select name='P_`+ idDiv + `' id='P_` + idDiv + `' class='browser-default' onChange='sel_precio(this.id,` + idDiv + `)'>
                                    <option value="" disabled selected><?php echo $seleccion ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                        $contador = 0;
                                        $sel = $ped->lista_productos($id_sucursal);
                                        while($p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel)){ if($contador > 1){  ?>
                                        <option value='<?php echo $p['id_producto'] ?>'><?php echo $p['producto'] ?></option>
                                    <?php }$contador++;} mysqli_free_result($sel);?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                    <div class='input-field col s7 m1'>
                                        <input name='M_`+ idDiv + `' id='M_` + idDiv + `' type='checkbox' onClick='marcarMEDICAL()'/>
                                        <label for="medical"></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='input-field' hidden>
                                        <select name='p_`+ idDiv + `' id='p_` + idDiv + `' class='browser-default' disabled>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected><?php echo $seleccion ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                            $contador = 0;
                                            $sel = $ped->lista_productos($id_sucursal);
                                            while($p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel)){if($contador > 1){
                                        ?>
                                            <option value='<?php echo $p['id_producto'] ?>'><?php echo $p['precio'] ?></option>
                                            <?php }$contador++;} mysqli_free_result($sel);?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='input-field col s12 m3'>
                                        <input name='T_`+ idDiv + `' id='T_` + idDiv + `' type='text' class='validate' onKeyup="cambio_preciomanual(this.id)" value="0">
                                        <label for='T_`+ idDiv + `'>Total</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='input-field col s12 m1'>
                                        <a href="#" id='divplantillas`+ idDiv + `' onClick='quitar(this.id)'><i class='material-icons' style='color:red'>remove_shopping_cart</i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cols s12">
                                    <div class="col s12  teal lighten-3 black-text text-darken-2 hidden" style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);" id="divDescripcion`+ idDiv + `"><p id="descripcionProducto`+ idDiv + `"></p></div>                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`);
```

Comment: Hola, creo que podrías intentar usar [Plantillas de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) para evitar esos errores.

Comment: Si usas ` (backtick) insertas variables haciendo ${idDiv}, no uses `+`

Comment: Posible duplicado de [no selecciona checkbox al darle click](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290842/no-selecciona-checkbox-al-darle-click)

Comment: todo el documento esta en script no tiene php

Comment: ya lo cambie y no funciona <input name='M_${idDiv}' id='M_${idDiv}' type='checkbox' onClick='marcarMEDICAL()' />

Comment: `<?php echo $seleccion ?>` claramente es php, javascript se ejecuta en el cliente y php en el servidor. Mira esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/159529/ejecutar-codigo-php-dentro-de-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Sustituye las comillas simples ( ' ) por dobles ( " ) y los acentos inversos: ( ` ) por comilla simple ( ' )

Eg.

```
 $('#masplantillas').append('<div class="ol s12"  id="divplantillas ' + idDiv + '" >');
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de usar las [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) sería la siguiente además de darle formato a tus atributos de cada etiqueta(opcional para mejor legibilidad):

```js
$("#masplantillas").append(`
  <div 
    id="divplantillas${idDiv}"
    class="col s12"
  >
    <div class="input-field col s2 m3">
      <select 
        id="C_${idDiv}"
        onChange="total(this.id)"
        name="C_${idDiv}"
        class="browser-default validate" 
        required
      >
        <option value="" selected disabled>0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
`)
```

Answer (score 0):

encontre el problema

es por materialize le tengo que agregar un id al label
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52618/error-grave-con-checkbox-de-materialize-css)

```
 <div class="input-field col s7 m1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="medical${idDiv}" name="medical[]" onClick="marcarMEDICAL(this)">  
        <label for="medical${idDiv}"></label>
 </div>
```